# zend framework rowset of rows, all same class

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'd like to use the same class as a row class and a base class for getting results, but think I am doing it the wrong way...

Ie I need the same class to extend `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` and `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` but think this is putting logic for two different things into the same class? (and extending two is impossible)..

For example, I think the base class should handle select queries etc, and the row class should handle updating etc. But I'd like to be able to go:

```
class Article extends BaseModel { //Set table name and some custom functions }

BaseModel { //Define custom functions for finding rows and updating }

Article::findAll() //This is table logic

Article::insert($data); //This is row login
```

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [ActiveRecord pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html):

> An object that wraps a row in a database table or view, encapsulates the database access, and adds domain logic on that data.

There is a proposal for a [`Zend_Db_ActiveRecord`](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Db_ActiveRecord) component, but it never left the "New" stage. There is a number of UseCases in the proposal though, which might give you some ideas how to implement that yourself. You might also be interested in using existing 3rd party solutions, like [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) or [phpactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)

[Please be aware that ActiveRecord is often misused and has a number of drawbacks due to the violation of separation of concerns due to the intermingling of db access and business logic in one class.](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/why_active_record_sucks.html)

Comment: This is what I want, shame ZF hasn't developed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing this is to have two classes - one for rows (some kind of a model) and for the table (some kind of mapper).
Why do you want to have them in one class? Isn't it the intention of classes to seperate stuff that doesn't belong together (directly)?
If you really want it to be in the same class, and a method `getTable` to the row-class and extend the row class to be an adapter to the table class (which I strongly dis-suggest of course :).